# problem with css div

Tags: html, css

sir,
i created a div tag in my html page and that displays a product.inside the product_box div i have two columns (lleft and right) using float.

both columns fit in the product_box dividing the container into two vertical halves.but when i type content in the right half the content comes out of the div if it is longer than one line.i want that i continue typing multiple lines and it fits inside the right half.

i dnt want the overflow:scroll; method or hidden as well coz the scroll bar looks very bad.

plz suggest a way to acheive this.

**CSS:**

```
#content_left .product_box {
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.left {
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    width:178px;
    height: 174px;
}


.right {    
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
    width: 396px;
    height: 136px;  
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="product_box">
   <h3>Product Title</h3>
   <div class="left">some content here</div>
   <div class="right">
     jhkdjfhkjhkjhkjhkhkhkhkjhkjhkjhkjhkhkhkh
   </div>         

   <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min-hieght` instead of `height` to ensure it gets minimum height and grows if the content increases...

and be sure too add float clearer like: `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the floating divs... in order to make parent container take its height

Comment: i have tried with min-height but the content is still growing and overflowing towards the right of the div .the content stays only in one line and overall page size increases horizontly. but its not coming to second line and filling the div vertically

Answer (score 0):

Add an element at the end of your div with the style clear:both; ( and maybe height:1px; )